# Italic not working in XML?

Tags: xml, italic

Can anyone explain why all HTML tags are working/rendering in my XML but italic  ?
Also, you can't put classes in xml right, I tried that it it didn't seem to recognized any classes.

Sorry getting familiar with XML

Comment: XML has no semantics per se. Whatever you're doing there with HTML tags is up to the application reading the XML to interpret. Care to share some code, mayhaps?

Comment: Please explain what you mean. XML is not a display language like HTML, so it doesn't have "italics". Please show the XML you're trying to use and explain how you use it and what exactly doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

XML has a CDATA function to pass characters used in the language.

There is a nice explanation to it here: http://www.w3schools.com/xmL/xml_cdata.asp

Comment: Ya, I read this earlier, but it doesn't really explain why <b>Bold</b> works but  <i>italic</i> does not work?

Comment: There is no '<i>italic</i>" in xml - xml describes data, html describes display

Comment: Then why does <b>bold</b> work then? This is info inside xml tag, I'm not using <i> to describe data

Comment: I don't understand why you want to be able to do this anyway, what is the Xml interpreting?

Comment: Sorry, should have explained.  I have a paragraph the XML is spitting out, but inside the paragraph the client would like to have certain words bold or italicized.  So I am putting in html tags in the xml.  They all work but Italic?

Comment: And what is the client interpreting the XML with?